# How do i mask and unmask HTML header text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my html document I have an `h3` header which text is a currency value.
I don't want this money value to be visible until user clicks a button to unmask it.

How do I have a button to mask or unmask this HTML element and still retain the currency formatting?

Comment: Use `.hide()` and `.show()`.

Comment: What do you mean by mask?  Do you mean replace with *s?  Also, please provide code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default of the `h3` to `display: none;`, then set the `onclick` attribute to a function, and make the function do 
`function show(){document.getElementById('show_button').style.display= 'block';}`

Answer (score 0):

Create an event to `show()` or `hide()` this value. 
You can also insert your text to an span and modify its css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a span to the text you want to obfuscate, then select this span with a js selector `document.querySelector()` or similar and add custom styling to it like hidden:

```
const span = document.querySelector('.currencySpan');
span.addEventListener('click', function() {
span.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

On your CSS add a hidden class:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result [Mattia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10626207/mattia-rasulo) has suggested using a ternary operator.

```js
const h3 = document.querySelector('.currencyMaskHeader');

document.querySelector('.maskToggleButton').onclick = function() {
  h3.style.visibility === 'visible' ?
    h3.style.visibility = 'hidden' :
    h3.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```